# Ansible: первое ssh подключение

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

Подскажите, как организовать Ansible-серверу первое подключение к большому количеству серверов на Linux без ввода пароля или отправления через ssh-copy-id готового ssh-ключа. Ведь, если серверов больше 100 это будет огромной рутиной.

Comment: А откуда взялись эти сервера? В общем случае то место, откуда они появились должно подложить на них ваш публичный ключ, а как иначе вы это себе представляете?

Comment: То есть, все равно нужно как-то вручную положить ssh pub key на каждый из этих серверов?

Comment: Я бы написал плейбук, который пробует подключиться по известным ключам\логин-паролям к серверам и укладывающий в туда нужный ключ.

Comment: @Sheridan проблема курицы и яйца. Откуда там появится известный ключ/пароль? А если мы как-то умеем это делать, то почему бы сразу не положить нужный ключ.

Comment: @AlexeyTen если переводят на ансибл уже существующий парк серверов, то сей список буцдет как минимум в голове у админа. Если же с нуля всё это, то надо разворачивать хосты ансиблом (начиная с генерирования виртуалок в гипервизорах), сразу подкладывая нужные ключи.

Comment: а эти 100 серверов между собой не общаются, возможно у них уже есть ключ, который можно использовать на новом сервере

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно заметили - это проблема курицы и яйца. Действия зависят от входных данных.

- Если уже существующий парк переводится на управление ансиблом, то нужно так или иначе на эти сервера разложить ключ. Либо руками, либо скриптом, перебирая известные ключи-логины-пароли. Ситуация сильно упрощается, если на всех серверах уже есть пользователь-sudoer с известным логином-паролем или с зарегестрированным ключом. В таком случае просто пишем плейбук с become в root и выкладываем нужный ключ.
- Если это новый парк серверов, то лучшим выходом будет деплой этих серверов с нуля, возможно даже начиная с создания виртуалок. Ну и, соответственно, укладка ключа во время создания сервера.
- Ну и третий, lazy-вариант. По сути первый, но ансиблирование хоста в момент возникновения необходимости там что-то сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Использую такой bash скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  echo "ping $line"
  if ping -c 1 $line &> /dev/null
then
  echo "running $line"
    sshpass -p <пароль> ssh-copy-id user@$line -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"
else
  echo "$line недоступен"
fi
done < "server.list"
```

В файл server.list перечисляем все IP.