# Ansible connect ssh key authorization

Tags: ansible

Начал изучать ансибл и возник вопрос, как правильно и Безопасно рекомендуется подключать клиентов к серверу Ансибл?
Самый очевидный вариант это прокидывать открытый ssh ключ сервера клиенту с помощью ssh-copy-id. А если мне нужно будет подключить разом например 100 виртуалок, мне нужно будет 100 раз прокидывать ключ и 100 раз вводить пароль? Какая самая простая и быстрая возможность подключить большое количество клиентов к серверу Ансибл? Можно ли на сервер Ансибл создать директорию с открытыми ключами клиентов и в файле hosts прописать ссылку к открытому ключу каждого клиента? Если да то можно пример?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ansible: первое ssh подключение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048807/ansible-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-ssh-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)